# conditions in extbase / fluid TYPO3

Tags: typo3, conditional-statements, fluid, extbase

im trying to check if the given variable is true or not so i can show different links to the user

```
<f:if condition="{response.isAuthenticated} == true">
    <f:then>
        <a href="{response.logoutURL}">logout</a>
    </f:then>
    <f:else>
        <a href="{response.loginURL}">login</a>
    </f:else>
</f:if>
```

the above snippet always returns true

what am i doing wrong ?

im using TYPO3 6.1.3 
this a part of an extension built with the extension manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try:

```
<f:if condition="{response.isAuthenticated}">
```

?

Comment: i have tried before at a certain point but it wasnt working but now it does thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
<f:security.ifAuthenticated>
Your Code
</f:security.ifAuthenticated>
```

Worked for me using TYPO3 6.1.7

Answer (score -1):

```
<f:if condition="{response.isAuthenticated}">
        <f:then>
            <a href="{response.logoutURL}">logout</a>
        </f:then>
        <f:else>
            <a href="{response.loginURL}">login</a>
        </f:else>
</f:if>
```

Comment: This should be avoided *unless* the action is either not cached or the page including arguments gets cached with a unique cHash for each user. Otherwise subsequent visitors will see protected content. The correct way is `<f:security.ifAuthenticated>`.